# Reading comma delimited file into a multidimensional array in Java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I want to read a list of multiple choice questions into a multidimensional array in Java, the file is in the format: **Question,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,correctanswer**.

> How many meters are in a kilometer?,1,10,100,1000,4,
>   Which colour isn't in the rainbow nursery rhyme?,Blue,Pink,Black,Orange,3
>   How many players does a football team have on the pitch?,10,11,12,13,2

And so I want the array to be in the format Question[][] where if n was 1 then Question[n][1] would be the first question in the CSV file, then to select a question I can just change n to whatever I want.

I don't know how many questions there will be, they will be continuously added or removed from the CSV file so there isn't going to be a static amount. So the question is how do I load all of the Questions from the CSV file in a simple way?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Can you use third party libraries? Otherwise do you need to account for escaping and quoting?

Comment: I've been using a simple CSV reading tutorial at [link](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/java-csv-file-reader.html), but I run into problems immediately because I want a multidimensional array, and you can't even declare one of those without knowing how many rows it will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to a point where you have to make a two-dimensional array for data hierarchy, you should probably create a sensible model for it.

Here is a quick (and dirty) model for you (setters discarded for typing speed):

Questionnaire class:

```
/**
 * Facilitates an entire questionnaire
 */
public class Questionnaire extends ArrayList<Question> {

    /**
     * This questionnaire's name
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * Creates a new questionnaire using the specified name
     * @param name  The name of this questionnaire
     */
    public Questionnaire(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this questionnaire
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Question class:

```
/**
 * Facilitates a question and its answers
 */
public class Question extends ArrayList<Answer> {

    /**
     * The question's text
     */
    private String text;

    /**
     * Constructs a new question using the specified text
     * @param text  The question's text
     */
    public Question(String text) {
        this.text = test;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this question's text
     */
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer class:

```
/**
 * Facilitates an answer
 */
public class Answer {

    /**
     * The answer's text
     */
    private String text;

    /**
     * Whether or not this answer is correct
     */
    private boolean correct;

    /**
     * Constructs a new answer using the specified settings
     * @param text          The text of this answer
     * @param correct       Whether or not this answer is correct
     */
    public Answer(String text, boolean correct) {
        this.text = text;
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this answer's text
     */
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * Whether or not this answer is correct
     */
    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }
}
```

Usage for it would be as follows:

```
// Create a new questionnaire
Questionnaire questionnaire = new Questionnaire("The awesome questionnaire");

// Create a question and add answers to it
Question question = new Question("How awesome is this questionnaire?");
question.add(new Answer("It's pretty awesome", false));
question.add(new Answer("It's really awesome", false));
question.add(new Answer("It's so awesome my mind blows off!", true));

// Add the question to the questionnaire
questionnaire.add(question);
```

Iterating over it is pretty easy:

```
// Iterate over the questions within the questionnaire
for(Question question : questionnaire) {
    // Print the question's text
    System.out.println(question.getText());

    // Go over each answer in this question
    for(Answer answer : question) {
        // Print the question's text
        System.out.println(answer.getText());
    }
}
```

You could also iterate just a part of it:

```
// Iterate over the third to fifth question
for (int questionIndex = 2; questionIndex < 5; questionIndex ++) {
    // Get the current question
    Question question = questionnaire.get(questionIndex);

    // Iterate over all of the answers
    for (int answerIndex = 0; answerIndex < question.size(); answerIndex++) {
        // Get the current answer
        Answer answer = question.get(answerIndex);
    }
}
```

Reading a file into the model using the format you described can be done the following way:

```
// Create a new questionnaire
Questionnaire questionnaire = new Questionnaire("My awesome questionnaire");

// Lets scan the file and load it up to the questionnaire
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));

// Read lines from that file and split it into tokens
String line, tokens[];
int tokenIndex;
while (scanner.hasNextLine() && (line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    tokens = line.split(",");

    // Create the question taking the first token as its text
    Question question = new Question(tokens[0]);

    // Go over the tokens, from the first index to the one before last
    for (tokenIndex = 1; tokenIndex < tokens.length-1; tokenIndex++) {
        // Add the incorrect answer to the question
        question.add(new Answer(tokens[tokenIndex], false));
    }

    // Add the last question (correct one)
    question.add(new Answer(tokens[tokenIndex],true));
}

// Tada! questionnaire is now a complete questionnaire.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is still that I have to read the questions in from somewhere, the end user will never ever have access to the code and it won't be maintained by the programmer so the only way the questions will be changed is through an external file. Appreciate your humor in the questionnaire :D. Edit: Oh hello edit :D

Comment: Well, this is not just good practice it's also going to make your life easier. Instead of trying to solve a mind boggling (relative to the person of course) algorithmic problem, you can solve it by laying out your data correctly and save time. Even though it seem like more work, it's actually not.

Comment: Thanks this looks perfect, I'll change it to fit in with my program but this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: One more thing if you're still there, the iteration of the questions and answers within the questionnaire doesn't work. They are definitely being added to the questionnaire, I have printed out the questions and answers as they were being passed in, but if I want to display either the full list or a single set of questions/answers within the questionnaire it doesn't work.

Comment: You can get the second answer of a question, for example, like so: `question.get(1)`, or the first question of a questionnaire like so: `questionnaire.get(0)`. To get the fourth answer of the fourth question, you could do the following: `questionnaire.get(3).get(3)`, much like a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Edited my answer to include iterating over just a part of it. Anyhow, each of those classes (except for `Answer`) is inheriting the entire behavior of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so you can go over its functionality

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is create an `ArrayList` or arrays. This seems complex, but using the `ArrayList` means you don't have to worry about the amount of questions.

```
ArrayList<String[]> questions = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// Create the object to contain the questions.

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("path to file"));
// Create a scanner object to go through each line in the file.

while(s.hasNextLine()) {
   // While lines still exist inside the file that haven't been loaded..
   questions.add(s.nextLine().split(","));
   // Load the array of values, splitting at the comma.
}
```

In the end, you wind up with an `ArrayList` object, where each entry is a `String[]` with the same length as the number of tokens on each line.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments on this answer, you can simply call the `toArray` method inside the `ArrayList` class, to get a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Obviously you can then call `toArray` at the end and have an array.

Comment: So the thing I just tried is String[][] questionsarray = questions.toArray();, but this comes up with an error, am I missing something basic? :(

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to String[][]"

Comment: Perhaps it's because inside the `ArrayList` class is a backend array that is used to store the data. The issue is that the backend array is not of type `String[][]`, so you're getting an exception from what. You may just have to stick to an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set up a nested for loop to handle this:

```
for(i = 0; i < number_of_questions; i++)
{
    line_array = current_input_line.split(",")
    Questions[i] = line_array[0]
    for(j = 1; j < line_array.length; j++)
    {
        Questions[i][j] = line_array[j];
    }
}
```